# Why do we use PolylineClass() instead of Polyline()?

Tags: arcobjects

I was wondering why we instantiate a class with a class word instead of just the name of the class?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to understand about ArcObjects is that it is mostly entirely written using Microsoft's Component Object Model (COM) which are native code modules. When referencing Arc COM objects in .NET, there are interop assemblies and types already created referred to as a Runtime Callable Wrappers (RCW). Now you can interact with RCW as if it is any other .NET type without worrying about most of the minutia of dealing with COM objects.

PolylineClass is the RCW for the polyline COM object. You also can't use PolylineClass directly if you set "Embed Interop Types" to true. To my knowledge there isn't anything other than convention necessitating that 'Class' be appended to the end of the type names.

Polyline is technically implemented as an interface, but it has the CoClassAttribute defined on it pointing at PolylineClass, meaning you can instantiate it. It's essentially a convenient way to deal with the RCWs without having to add 'Class' to the end of everything. Take a look at the definition of both and you'll see there is nothing in Polyline, but plenty in PolylineClass.